# RobotFramework POST request with Base64 content

Tags: json, api, base64, robotframework

I would really appreciate an example request for the following body data:

```
{
    "Content": "PD94bWwgdmVyc...F",
    "UserId": "user@mail.com",
    "FileName": "Test.txt"
}
```

This is JSON body and the **content** of the file should be represented as Base64 string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to compile a code that is able to send post requests with base64 content. This is good practice if you want to avoid pointing filepaths on your local machine.

N.B. JSONLibrary is required

```
Create Session    mysession   ${url}
&{headers}  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8     Authorization=${token}
${json}=    Catenate    {"Content": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2..."}   
${resp}    POST     url=${url}/api/endpoint   data=${json}    headers=${headers}
```

The status should be: `expected_status=200`

I am pretty sure that this code could be improved, feel free to contribute.